# Action for button in cell - Objective C

Tags: button, tableview, cell

I'm a beginner in Objective-C. I have a problem.
I have a tableview with 20 cells, it has "name" and "button" for each cell. I want when I click the button in cell, that button will be changed background image. But I don't know why, when I click button in cell #1 it change background but button in cell #8 also auto change background. Anyone have any idea? Please help me.

```
    -(void)clickLike:(UIButton*)sender
    {
    UIImage *curImg = sender.currentImage;
    UIImage *like = [UIImage imageNamed:@"like.png"];
    UIImage *dislike = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dislike.png"];

    if(curImg==like){
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dislike.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        sender.selected = TRUE;

        //Insert dislike song
        SongObject *list = [self.arrSong objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
        idUser=@"1";
        idSong=list.idsong;
        [self dislikeSong:idSong and:idUser];

    }
    else if(curImg==dislike){
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        sender.selected = TRUE;

        //Insert like song
        SongObject *list = [self.arrSong objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
        idUser=@"1";
        idSong=list.idsong;
        [self likeSong:idSong and:idUser];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

button in cell #1 and button in cell #8 are same UIButton Object, the problem is not in this method. You must have two button pointed to one UIButton Object. Check the code where button #1 and button #8 are created.

Comment: Thanks for comment. But I custom cell include label "name" and button "click", then it auto load in tableview. It mean the same method, the same UIButton Object.

Comment: what I said is somewhat arbitrary, button in cell #1 and button in cell #8 cannot be same UIButton Objects, but I believe the problem is not in this method, it seems that clickLike method was invoked twice on button#1 and button#8 in one click action, so check the code where click events happened. What's more, donot use curImg==like and curImg==dislike, the UIImage cache may be invalid and unexpected things happen. At last, have you noticed that you have same code "sender.selected = TRUE;" in both "if" and "else if" block?

Comment: It seems that nothing wrong. Try NSLog(sender.tag) in clickLike method, you can see this method is invoked twice actually.

Comment: Here is call action for button. The problem is not only cell#1 and cell#8, but also cell#2 and cell#9. I think it has default distance. The background is auto change but when I call function get row it just show exactly row which I click. 
>cell.btnLike.tag = indexPath.row; [cell.btnLike setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dislike.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; [cell.btnLike addTarget:self action:@selector(clickLike:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: that is strange. I can't see anything wrong in the code. If you don't mind, send your project to zhangbodut@gmail.com and maybe I can have a try.

Comment: Thanks, @blindpirate. I don't know why does it has that error but I try to add an parameter to save the status "selected" or "not selected" then it work well.